ReactPlayer Youtube link refuses to connect only on Microsoft Edge
I'm currently attempting to use react-player to link youtube videos within a react component. Currently, it seems like Microsoft Edge has some sort of default setting that Youtube doesn't allow to connect with:
Edge Local Host:

Chrome Local Host:

My initial thought is that this could do with edge's settings within the local host since the documentation allows for the player to show videos:
Edge, package documentation demo:

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.
